# Find the relationship match in sql

Tags: mysql

If I got 2 table, which is
[image]
How do I get the result of

[image]

I know combine the name is using CONCAT_WS function, but I don't understand how can I exchange the row such as the "wife" and "husband" on my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the client table two time (of of each related  part in row) using tablename alias

```
select 
        concat(c1.client_firstname, ' ' , c1.client_lastname) as A_Name
      , r.rel_client1_state as A_State
      , concat(c2.client_firstname, ' ' , c2.client_lastname) as B_Name
      , r.rel_client2_state as B_State
from relationships as  r
inner join client as c1 on r.rel_client1_id = c1.client_id
inner join clinet as c2 on r.rel_client2_id = c2.client_id
```

Comment: So that's mean I can join the table for more than 2 time? I though can up to 1 only.

Comment: You can join a table whenever you want ... just use aliases appropriate and use the right column for joins

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you.^^

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', c1.client_firstname, c1.client_lastname) as c1name,
r.rel_client1_state, CONCAT_WS(' ', c2.client_firstname, c2.client_lastname) as c2name, 
r.rel_client2_state FROM client c1 
JOIN relationship r ON c1.client_id = r.rel_client1_id 
JOIN client c2 ON c2.client_id = r.rel_client2_id WHERE 1
```